# How to connect to a PostgreSQL server via JDBC in Android?

Tags: android, database, postgresql, jdbc

I have to connect to a PostgreSQL server in LAN without web service.
At the moment I think JDBC is the only way I can consider of.

How can I fulfill this? Is there any ready-to-use 3rd party library I can import to my Android project?

Any reply would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a direct connection between mobile devices and the database server is really what you want (no security concerns) then you wouldn't need any additional library? Just deploy the JDBC driver on android, I guess...?

An other option would be to create a mini web server in front of the PosgreSQL server, containing the JDBC driver. Then you could define a simple protocol of sending/receiving SQL/resultsets via HTTP. The advantage of this is, your application footprint on the mobile device is smaller.

Comment: That's scary-bad security, be careful @user617389. Imagine the havoc someone who pulled the security credentials out of your .apk could wreak if you're doing things this way. Much safer to write a constrained web service to do the required work; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881538/how-can-i-securely-indirectly-query-a-postgresql-database-within-android/10890705#10890705

Answer (score 8):

You can find people talking about deploying the JDBC driver to talk to PostgreSQL on the [pgandroid](http://groups.google.com/group/pgandroid) mailing list.  Some examples there and if you run into problems that's the right place to ask for help.  I believe the regular .jar files work fine with recent Android versions, but you may have to patch things to add compatibility with older Android versions.

The other option if you don't want to use Java/JDBC is to use the [psqldroid](http://code.google.com/p/psqldroid/) library.

Comment: Direct access to Pg from Android is going to be hard to make safe if the .apk is public. Imagine the mess you could make by pulling the credentials of the .apk. Safer approach (more network-efficient too): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881538/how-can-i-securely-indirectly-query-a-postgresql-database-within-android/10890705#10890705