# PostgreSQL JDBC connection fails on Android 4.0

Tags: android, postgresql, jdbc, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Does anyone knows what can I do to make JDBC connection work on Android 4.0. It works fine on Android 1.6-2.3. I use Dave Cramer's build: 
http://groups.google.com/group/pgandroid/browse_thread/thread/d8b400f039f66d5f/f77b2e2a99370a36?lnk=raot#f77b2e2a99370a36

The Logcat says:

```
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.belonogov.connectjdbc/com.belonogov.connectjdbc.ConnectJDBCActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at com.belonogov.connectjdbc.ConnectJDBCActivity$CustomDrawableView.<init>(ConnectJDBCActivity.java:81)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at com.belonogov.connectjdbc.ConnectJDBCActivity.onCreate(ConnectJDBCActivity.java:27)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  
... 11 more
```

It's just a simple application that connects to a database.

Comment: You'll find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception). You have to use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 2):

If at all possible, consider moving away from direct JDBC on your android device. It's inefficient in terms of round trips, etc, and isn't robust in the face of unreliable connections.

See [How can I securely (indirectly) query a postgresql database within android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881538/how-can-i-securely-indirectly-query-a-postgresql-database-within-android/10890705#10890705) .

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I start to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will find the answer here:

```
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):      at com.belonogov.connectjdbc.ConnectJDBCActivity$CustomDrawableView.<init>(ConnectJDBCActivity.java:81)
06-10 17:35:51.043: E/AndroidRuntime(798):      at com.belonogov.connectjdbc.ConnectJDBCActivity.onCreate(ConnectJDBCActivity.java:27)
```

This means: Lookup the class `ConnectJDBCActivity.java`, line 81 and look what reference might be `null`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes, I know. The lines such as :st = connection.createStatement(); rs = st.executeQuery(query);rs.next(); give NullPointerException. But it works fine with older versions of Android. Can I do something with that?